# Imbricated loops + timeout sometimes fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, timeout

I made a little script to practice and it seems I have a problem with my loops and their timeouts.
Here's the link to my script : http://codepen.io/JulienBarreira/pen/EWNoxJ

Sometimes when a word is writing, one or two letters are wrong. For example, instead of "cheeseburger", I get "chkesebxrger".

I found a little trick so it fails less, but i don't know why at all.

```
  function charsAnim(i, word, j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var count = j; 
      if (j < steps) {           
        randomChar(i, word, count, j);
      } else {
        goodChar(i, word, count, j);
      }
      /* seems it fails less if I divide j, don't know why */
    }, (speed/steps)*(j / 1.8));
  }
```

The problems appears more often when others scripts are running on the computer (for example in my profile page).

Feel free to give me any advices about my code even if it's not about my problem. There's problably an easier way to do the same thing and i'm here to progress.

Thanks :)

Edit : I added 3 iframes in a snippet to show you the problem, when you start the snippet, the first word fails most of the time.

```js
var words = [
  'unicorn',
  'cheeseburger',
  'pizza',
  'pineapple',
  'popsicle',
  'bubbles',
  'seagull',
  'doodle',
  'goggles',
  'artichoke',
  'potato',
  'carrot',
  'vegeta'
];
var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#%&^+=-";
var speed = 250;
var steps = 4;

function getRandomWord() {
  var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  return randomWord;
}
function getRandomLetter() {
  var randomLetter = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  return randomLetter;
}

function randomWordLoop() {
  var word = getRandomWord();
  var textLength = word.length;
  for(i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {    
    letterAppear(i, word);
  }  
  
  function letterAppear(i, word) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      randomLetters(i, word);    
    }, speed*i);  
  }

  function randomLetters(i, word) {
    for (j = 0; j <= steps; j++) {
      charsAnim(i, word, j);
    }
  }

  function charsAnim(i, word, j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var count = j; 
      if (j < steps) {           
        randomChar(i, word, count, j);
      } else {
        goodChar(i, word, count, j);
      }
      /* seems it fails less if I divide j, don't know why */
    }, (speed/steps)*(j / 1.8));
  }

  function randomChar(i, word, count, j) {
    var letter = getRandomLetter();
    if (j > 0) {
      var oldText = $('#loader').text().slice(0, -1);
    } else {
      var oldText = $('#loader').text();
    }
    $('#loader').text(oldText + letter);    
  }
  function goodChar(i, word, count, j) {
    var oldText = $('#loader').text().slice(0, -1);  
    $('#loader').text(oldText + word[i]);
    if (i == textLength - 1 ) {
      removeWord();
    }
  }
  
  function removeWord() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      for (k = 0; k < textLength; k++) {
        removeLetters(k);
      }
    }, speed*2);
  }
  function removeLetters(k) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      removeLetter(k);
    }, 75*k);
  }
  function removeLetter(k) {
    var actualText = $('#loader').text().slice(0, -1);
    $('#loader').text(actualText);
    if (k == textLength - 1) {
      randomWordLoop();
    }
  }
}

randomWordLoop();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #010101;
}
.loader {
  width: 300px;
  color: #0c9c73;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Roboto Mono;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.loader:after {
    content:'_';
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GquEnoqZAK0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GquEnoqZAK0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GquEnoqZAK0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you include full `javascript` at Question?

Comment: No problem it's done

Comment: Cannot reproduce issue.

Comment: It's working perfectly when only this script is running on a page, but when there's multiple scripts running at the same time or if I'm on a bad computer I have the issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bad computer". Can you reproduce   "multiple scripts running at the same time" issue at stacksnippets?

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language. By "bad computer" i mean a computer with a weak CPU for example. I've added a snippet and 3 iframes in it to show you. When you launch it, the first word should fail  (run it again if it doesn't).

Comment: No worries. english language is not relevant to the issue described at OP. Not sure how links to videos reproduce demonstration of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combining this loop, inside `randomWordLoop()`

```
for(i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {    
  letterAppear(i, word);
}
```

... with the `setTimeout()` inside `letterAppear()`. Basically, when `letterAppear()` executes inside `letterAppear`, `i` variable no longer has the same value as when you set the timeout. It has it's global value, which might have already been set to a completely different value by any other function in your page that might use `i`.

Also, please note the proper way to set your for would be not to use `i` globally, but rather set it as a local var of your function: `for(var i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {...}`.

You're not able to properly see it, as your function outputs random letters and there's no visual clue letting you know it runs on wrong values of `i`, but I believe your function is wrong most of the time.

To fix this, you need a closure in `letterAppear()` which will pass the correct values of `i` and `word` to the `setTimeout()` inside `randomLetters()`, irrespective of their global value when the contents of the `setTimeout()` executes:

```
for(var i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {    
  (function(i,word){
    letterAppear(i, word);
  })(i,word)
}
```

Looking closer to your code, you might need closures in more than one place (if it's important that the values you pass to the functions are the same at code execution) and you should also define the `for` iterators (`i` and `j`) locally, using `var`, like I did above.

Don't forget your best `JavaScript` friend ever:

```
console.log(this, arguments);
```

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks. I was sloppy. Focusing too much on the wording, didn't check my syntax.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately it's not fixing my problem. I've added the closure for my first loop, and it doesn't change anything. I tried  to add a closure to my 2 others loops (j and k). I changed my vars to local vars too

Comment: What you should do is slow your script to an easily debuggable speed (x10 or x20) and use console log to fully understand what goes on and when.

Comment: I tried to clean it up and understand what you're doing. Here's what I got, hope it helps: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pePBML?editors=0010. I made all the functions vars and tried to contain them. All I did was apply sane principles to what you have, I didn't have the time to fully understand what goes on, as I find it confusing and overly complex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time ! I think I've found something by speeding up my code (it never fails when I slow it down). I've added consoles.log on my randomChar and goodChar functions, and it seems when a letter fails, it's because the loops for the next letter starts even if the loop for the previous letter isn't finished, so my good letter comes too late to replace the one it's supposed to. It's hard to explain so I reused your cleaned pen to make another one with consoles log to show you : http://codepen.io/JulienBarreira/pen/RpVOxb I'm actually tring to find a solution

Comment: You're welcome. My SO time for today has ran out, I'll probably have a look at it tomorrow. Good luck and happy coding!   :: }<(((*> ::)

Comment: I totally forgot this questions ! Thanks for your help, I made another version from sratch some monthes ago, it's working perfectly even on slow computers now.
https://codepen.io/JulienBarreira/pen/Nvjjmm